# Cannot match any routes?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
  RouterModule.forChild([

     { path: ":offerId/:specId/:activeIndex", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent  } 
)]
```

But im getting this error:

> Cannot match any routes

Any suggestion how can i do dynamic path based on number of params?

I have this:

```
  RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: "vpn/evidencija", component: VpnEvidencijaComponent  },
            { path: ":offerId/:specId/:activeIndex/basket/load", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent },
            { path: ":offerId/:specId", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent  },
            { path: ":offerId/:specId/:activeIndex", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent  } 
         ])]
```

Now on start im in vpn/evidencija and that works, but on that page i have link that goes to vpn/evidencija/11/0 and then i get error : Cannot match any routes.

Comment: No, he shouldn't ;-)

Comment: path can not start with /

Comment: It's not enough information. What action causes this error? If this is the only route in your system, then just loading `index.html` would probably cause this error. You have no route that matches when no parameters are passed.

Comment: try recompile again

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i updated my question

Comment: You need to ensure the more specific routes are sorted before the less specific ones. Angular takes the first route that matches. You still don't have a route that matches when no path (parameters) are provided.

Comment: first one is vpn/evidencija is without paramteres...and i get that page ...and then i have link to vpn/evidencija/111/1 and there i get an error even if i have   { path: ":offerId/:specId", component: VpnEvidencijaFlowComponent  }